# Invalid JSON RPC response

Tags: contract-design, contract-debugging, truffle-contract

I am trying to wire my smart contract with Oraclize to get random numbers. Here's my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

import "./usingOraclize.sol";

contract Blackjack is usingOraclize{

   uint public random;

   event Paid(address indexed _from, uint _value);

   function() external payable {
       Paid(msg.sender, msg.value);
   }

   function Blackjack() public {
       OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0x6f485C8BF6fc43eA212E93BBF8ce046C7f1cb475);
   }

   function getRandom() public constant {
       oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(0, 4, 200000);
   }

   function __callback(bytes32 _queryId, string _result, bytes _proof) public{
        random = uint(keccak256(_result)) % 52 + 1;
   }
}
```

I am using Ganache as a private blockchain (GUI).

Calling getRandom() causes the following stack trace in the truffle console

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"id":12,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\adimi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\adimi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:1)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\adimi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\adimi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:128:1)
at C:\Users\adimi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:134:1
at C:\Users\adimi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:86:1
at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\adimi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:1)
```

I have also sent 3 ether to the contract to cover for the Oraclize call.

Edit: I have set up ethereum-bridge and it is running when I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process worked for me on macOS:

Install truffle globally on your computer.

```
$ sudo npm install -g truffle
```

Install ganache-cli on your computer. The GUI version of Ganache will sadly no longer work for our purposes, as it lacks a feature that is necessary for ethereum bridge (unlocking accounts).

```
$ sudo npm install -g ganache-cli
```

Clone your repo (if you haven't already) and install node packages.

```
$ git clone <repo>
$ cd <repo>
$ npm install
```

We need to install ethereum bridge, which lets us make calls to Oraclize from our testing environment.

Install ethereum bridge. Don't do this inside the [repo] directory.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge.git
$ cd ethereum-bridge
$ npm install
```

Ethereum bridge (soon to be replaced by Stargate) needs an older version of node.

Install node version manager (nvm) using the instructions on this page: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md

Make sure the latest version of node is installed.

```
$ nvm install node
```

Start ganache-cli with latest node version (9.x as of this writing).

```
$ nvm use node
$ ganache-cli --unlock 0 --unlock 1 --deterministic --mnemonic "candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat"
```

Open a new terminal window, move to your ethereum bridge directory, and start ethereum bridge with node 6.9.1. It takes a while to finish starting.

```
$ cd etherem-bridge
$ nvm use 6.9.1
$ node bridge -H 127.0.0.1:8545 -a 1 --dev
```

Open a third terminal window and run the truffle tests in the [repo] directory with node 9.x

```
$ cd <repo>
$ nvm use node
$ truffle test
```

Interact with the application via Truffle console or via a front end application.

```
$ cd <repo>
$ nvm use node
$ truffle deploy
```

Tho I never made a call to getRandom(). URL call went thru successfully for me. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Are you sure about the limitation of the GUI ganache that you mentioned? I looked for any information on that but couldn't find anything related. I want to be completely sure before spending the time setting it up. I'm on windows and installing nvm is a bit trickier.

Comment: This was taken from the readme in my private repo. Don't worry, I didn't write all that just for you ;)

Comment: I don't really remember, but I think you need to "unlock" the account in order for bridge accept gas and function. GUI ganache doesn't have the unlock feature.

Comment: I've followed all of the steps, not I'm getting a revert so it's definitely progress. I think it's something to do with the gas limit so I'll play around with that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On a side note, do you know a good tutorial for ganache-cli, I couldn't find anything useful online. I can't figure out how to check an account's balance.

Comment: The readme in the github repo is probably one of the better resources out there: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli  as for checking balances, you could write a truffle test that gets the balance. I think you can also add the account to metamask and view the balance in there.

Comment: I got it to work with the ethereum price in USD example but still struggling with the random number query. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ethereum bridge to your local stack. Without it, Ganache will have no way to talk to the Oraclize contract.

https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have set that up as well, started it with
`node bridge -H localhost:7545 -a 1`